# Mongoose: Using custom function to convert value in query / aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, currency

My collection of products looks like this:

```
[{
  _id: '1',
  name: 'Car'
  price: {
    currency: 'EUR',
    value: 1200
  }
}, {
  _id: '2',
  name: 'TV'
  price: {
    currency: 'GBP',
    value: 150
  }
}, {
  _id: '3',
  name: 'Phone'
  price: {
    currency: 'USD',
    value: 240
  }
}]
```

Now, someone sends request to my backend to display all products with prices between 10 and 500 PLN. My idea is to get current exchange rates for base currency PLN, calculate the edge prices (10 and 500) on each iteration for every product's currency and see if the price is within the calculated range. The problem is that I cannot construct a proper query. I tried like this:

```
const query = [
    ...(req.query.priceFrom ? [{ "price.value": { "$gte": getCalculatedRange(req.query.priceFrom, '$price.currency') }}] : []),
    ...(req.query.priceTo ? [{ "price.value": {"$lte": getCalculatedRange(req.query.priceTo, '$price.currency') }}] : [])
];

const products = await Product.find({ $and: query });
```

As you can see I want to get correct ranges for current iterated product price, but the problem is that it's not possible (or maybe possible?) to pass values from current iteration (in my case: currency)  to function in order to get converted value. The text '$price.currency' is passed to the function instead of real value from the object (I know that's obvious and stupid from my side, but I want to illustrate it thoroughly and clear what I struggle with).

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with aggregation and combining operators like:

- $addFields - for creating temporary field to keep the converted price
- nested $switch for multiple currency cases:

  ```
  $switch: {
      branches: [
          {
              case: { $eq: ['eur', '$price.currency'] },
              then: { $multiply: ['$price.value', getRate(req.query.priceUnit.toLowerCase(), 'eur')] },
           }, {
              case: /* next case */
           }
     ],
     default: '$price.value'
  }
  ```
- $redact + $cond + $gte / $lte to check if converted price is in specific range (if yes: $$KEEP, otherwise: $$PRUNE)